# "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'" error while trying to make a class

Tags: python

why is my class not working?
I tried multiple solutions, non of them worked.
I am trying to make a class but I'm quite new  with classes. please help me out.

```
class db:

    def __init__(self, name, roof):

        self.name = name
        self.roof = roof



    def add(self):
        global roof

        roof = "+--------------------------------------------------------+"
        z = len(self.name)
        x = len(self.roof) - z


        for i in range(x - 4):
            self.name = self.name + " "
        print(self.roof)
        print("|", self.name, "|")


db.add("NAME")
db.add("AGE")
db.add("COUNTRY")
print(roof)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/User/Desktop/test/test.py", line 25, in <module>
    db.add("NAME")
  File "c:/Users/User/Desktop/test/test.py", line 15, in add
    z = len(self.name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: `I_AM_A_CLASS_OBJECT_NOT_AN_INSTANCE.add("I am a string with no name attribute")`; The first "self" parameter is only bound for *instances* created from class objects.

Comment: What @user2864740 wants to say is, that you need to create an instance of your class like this: `abc = db("Name",  "roof")` and then use `abc.add("NAME")`. Otherwise the constructor (`__init__`) is never called and your class has no attribute name

Comment: oh, now i get it. thanks @LeoE and user2864740.

Comment: @Cummo.exe note, try to follow standard Python naming conventions, where user-defined classes should use CapitalCase.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize class object first to call member function in class.

So first make class object

something like

```
_db = db('name', 'root')
```

And then call member function

```
_db.add("NAME")
_db.add("AGE")
_db.add("COUNTRY")
```

And class definition should be like below

```
class db:

    def __init__(self, name, roof):

        self.name = name
        self.roof = roof

    def add(self, name): # Because you are calling with one parameter
        global roof

        roof = "+--------------------------------------------------------+"
        z = len(self.name)
        x = len(self.roof) - z


        for i in range(x - 4):
            self.name = self.name + " "
        print(self.roof)
        print("|", self.name, "|")
```

Comment: Yes,  I am pointing one more problem out in class
one moment...

Comment: Inside class, `self` is point the own class out so when call member function, the first parameter self should not be considered as argument.